# Cascade annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have next classes:

```
 @Entity
  @Table(name="A")
  public class A{

@Id
@NextId(sequence="A_SEQ")
@Column(name="A_ID")
private long aId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="a", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<B> bSet;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a")
private Set<E> eSet;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<D>dSet;
 }


  @Entity
  @Table(name="B")
  public class B{

@Id
@NextId(sequence="B_SEQ")
@Column(name="B_ID")
private long bId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
private A a;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="b", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<C> cSet;
 }

  @Entity
  @Table(name="C")
  public class C{

@Id
@NextId(sequence="C_SEQ")
@Column(name="C_ID")
private long cId;

    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="B_ID")
private B b;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="c")
private Set<E> eSet;
 }

  @Entity
  @Table(name="D")
  public class D{

@Id
@NextId(sequence="D_SEQ")
@Column(name="D_ID")
private long dId;

    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
private A a;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="d", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<E> eSet;

 }

  @Entity
  @Table(name="E")
  public class E{

@Id
@NextId(sequence="E_SEQ")
@Column(name="E_ID")
private long eId;

    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="D_ID")
private D d;

    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="C_ID")
private C c;

    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
private A a;
 }
```

In additional I have getters and setters for all properties.

I want to save only A class and all other classes need to be saved by cascade.
But when I try to execute next lines:

```
newSess.saveOrUpdate(o);
newSess.flush();
```

I get next error:
    Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("E"."C_ID")

I understand that I got this error because C is transient. I think something wrong with cascade annotations.

How I can fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: quite confusing your example (Set<D> eSet, etc.). How do you insert your values into the sets? Remember that you have to assign the references correctly. i.e if you want to assign a B instance to an A instance then you might do something like this:

public void assignB(B b){
  bSet.add(b);
  b.setA(this);
}

Comment: Really in code I have existing in DB structure. I need to copy this structure, change Ids for all rows and save it in DB.

Comment: did you apply my suggestion? If the references within java are broken, then jpa cannot set the correct foreignkeys automatically